# drag polygon overlay - leaflet open source map API

Tags: maps, leaflet

I am creating a web application on maps, using open source maps. I have to create a polygon overlay which can be dragged anywhere on the map. I checked Leaflet API for this but I couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing the same thing. But having some problems while draging. Look into the wrapper L.Draggable in the source, this is used for dragging any element in leaflet